# Creating string permutations

Tags: c#, .net, permutation

Why doesn't this produce the correct number of string permutations? For

```
perm("ABC", 3)
```

it should print 27 different permutations.

```
private static List<string> permutated = new List<string>(30000);

public static List<string> perm(string s, int k) { return comb(s, "", k); }

private static List<string> perm(string s, string prefix, int k)
{
    if (k == 0)
    {
        permutated.Add(prefix);
    }
    else 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            perm( s.Substring( i + 1 ), prefix + s[i], k - 1 );
        }
    }
    return permutated;
}
```

Comment: What has your attempt at debugging shown you? What have you tried to do?

Comment: ABC has 6 permutations, not 27
ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA

Comment: Secondly, you never do anything with permuted besides return it.

Comment: Boo, I need combinations, not permutations.
and yes, I'm adding it to the list

Comment: ahh..ok, so how to I produce all possible combinations?
AAA, BBB, CCC, ABA, ACA.
I thought that premutation was distinct but combination had repeated letters

Comment: "and yes, I'm adding it to the list"

Where?

"it should print 27 different combinations."

What does it actually print?

Comment: sorry, I was printing it to the screen..anyway, I corrected it.
permutated.Add(prefix);

Comment: “My roommate says, I'm going to take a shower and shave, does anyone need to use the bathroom? It's like some weird quiz where he reveals the answer first.” - Mitch Hedberg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already calculating [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) in your program. For `comb("ABC", 3)` there should be one result.

If you want [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) instead (six results), replace `s.Substring( i + 1 )` in the recursive function call with `s.Substring(0, i) + s.Substring(i+1)`.

If you want 27 results, simply pass `s` instead of `s.Substring( i + 1 )`.